# Reading array of struct in different function in C

Tags: c, struct, pthreads, global-variables

Beginner here, again.

I've completed a code where there are many objects on the screen, each one of them has four parameters: position X, position Y, velocity X, velocity Y.

I've created arrays of integers and floats for my single threaded code and it works ok. But I can't track more than 100 objects because there are many calculations involved, so I've decided to split the task.

My original tracking functions accepts many parameters, but to invoke pthread_create, I need to pass everything through a single parameter, so I can't have this:

```
void reposition(float px, float py, float vx, float vy) {}
```

My idea is to create the following struct:

```
typedef struct{
  float px;
  float py;
  float vx;
  float vy;
} ObjectParameters;
```

convert all my code, and then pass it to the functions as a single parameter.

So to create my objects, I have now the following:

```
void createObjects() {
  int i;
  ObjectParameters* object = malloc(NOBJECTS * sizeof *object);


  srand(time(NULL));
  for (i=0;i<NOBJECTS;i++) {
    object[i].px = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
    object[i].py = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
    object[i].vx = -1.5+randf()*3.0;
    object[i].vy = -1.5+randf()*3.0;
    printf("%f %f %f %f\n",object[i].px, object[i].py, object[i].vx, object[i].vy);
    //printing anywhere within this function works fine.

  }
}

void anotherFunction() {
  // Here if I print the parameters for any i object, I get only zeros.
}
```

If I try to declare object outside of any function, I get a message saying that the element is not a compile-time constant.

How can I read my ObjectParameters from memory (and modify them, if required), from within another function?

Thanks, as always,
Saulo

Comment: `object` is local to `createObjects`, you can't access it in `anotherFunction`. Declare parameters to it and pass some at call point.

Comment: You haven't given us very much to work with here.  If the issue Jean-Baptiste pointed out is not characteristic of your real code -- and I am inclined to guess that it is not, since you claim to have derived your code from a version that works correctly with arrays of different element type -- then in fact, you've given us *nothing* useful.  It is very hard for us to help you without a [mre].

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, John. I am in the very beginning, so I didn't even know that this is not enough information. I will elaborate. For example, I don't even know how to make much sense of what Jean-Baptiste suggested. I elaborate further as soon as I have time.